# Did author omit trace in this problem statement?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I have this problem:

Prove that the following identity is true:

$$\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{A^T} = \sum_{i} \boldsymbol{a_i} \boldsymbol{a_i^T}$$

I assumed the notation $a_i$ means ith column vector of the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$.
I attempted to solve it and I believe the author of the problem meant to prove that:

$$ \text{tr}( \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{A^T}) = \sum_{i} \boldsymbol{a_i} \boldsymbol{a_i^T}$$

where $\text{tr}$ is trace of a matrix. Otherwise, I get an incorrect answer.

Am I correct?

Comment: $\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$I don't think they would have meant to show that $\tr\left(AA^{T}\right) = \sum\limits_{i} \color{red}{a_{i}a_{i}^{T}}$, because the left-hand side is a scalar but the right-hand side is a matrix. But if you make the right-hand side summand instead be $a_{i}^{T}a_{i}$ (OR if you take $a_{i}$ as the $i$-th *row* of $A$), then the equation would be correct.

Comment: Another possibility is that the $\color{red}>$ sign is a pure typo and should not be there; if that is the case, then perhaps they are asking you to show that $\color{blue}{AA^{T} = \sum\limits_{i} a_{i}a_{i}^{T}}$, where $a_{i}$ is the $i$-th column of $A$ (this is in fact true as well).

Comment: The > sign is my typo, I surrounded the expression in block quotes for nicer formatting which I shouldn't do because it messed up the expression by adding the > sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current equation ($AA^{T} = \sum\limits_{i}a_{i}a_{i}^{T}$ where $a_{i}$ is the $i$-th column of $A$), everything is fine. This is a correct equation (note that if $A$ is $m\times n$, then $a_{i}a_{i}^{T}$ is a matrix of size $m\times m$, as is $AA^{T}$, so the dimensions match up).

Comment: Thanks, there was a mistake in my reasoning, I will attempt to solve it again.

Comment: I solved it successfully, it was rather easy, I just messed up the dimensions as you suggested. Thanks for help again!